# Pass list of objects as individual parameters

Tags: groovy, parameters

I have two methods - named `one` and `two`. Method `one` takes a `List<Person>` where `person` is some class and method `two` takes individual objects of `Person` class.

How can I pass the `List<Person>` as individual object parameters to method `two`?
The `List` could contain 0 or 1 or more elements and I want to pass `null` if the list doesn't have all the 3 params required by method `two`.

```
def one (List<Person> persons) {

    // check the size of the list
    // pass arguments to method two

    // this works
    two(persons[0], persons[1], persons[2])

    //what I want is 
    two(persons.each { it  + ', '})
}

def two (Person firstPerson, Person secondPerson, Person thirdPerson) {

    // do something with the persons
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid using capitalised parameter names ie `persons` instead of `Persons`. Capitals can cause you grief sometimes, as groovy can occasionally guess you're on about a class

Comment: It was refactoring mistake when changing my correct class name with an example one. I don't do this in my daily programming. I edited the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the spread operator * for your calling method, but based on your comment "The List could contain 0 or 1 or more elements" you will want to use the variadic function for your second method.  Try this:

```
// Spread operator "*"
def one(List<Person> persons) {
  two(*persons)
}

//  Variadic function "..."
def two(Person... values) {
  values.each { person ->
    println person
  }
}
```

Now you can call the two method passing null, an empty list, or any number of Person instances such as:

```
two(null)
two([])
two(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5)
```

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
two(*persons)
```

`*` will split the list and pass its elements as separate arguments.

It will be:

```
def one (List<String> strings) {
    two(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2])
    two(*strings)
}

def two (String firstPerson = null, String secondPerson = null, String thirdPerson = null) {
   println firstPerson
   println secondPerson
   println thirdPerson 
}

one(['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Nice! It's almost right, but what if there are only two arguments? one(['a', 'b']). biniam wants to have null as missing one. Fortunately, there are default arguments in Groovy, so the complete solution would be two(String firstPerson = null, String secondPerson = null, String thirdPerson = null)